# Validate atleast and only one attr_accessible is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Ruby on Rails 3.
Have a form with two questions. I only want user to answer one of the two. How do you validate this?
Questions:

```
<div class="row" id="phonepbx" style=""> 
                                <ul>4a.  My customers have their own brand preferences regarding VoIP manufacturers.<br/>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "Strongly Agree") %>Strongly Agree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "Somewhat Agree") %>Somewhat Agree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "Neutral") %>Neutral</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "Somewhat Disagree") %>Somewhat Disagree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "Strongly Disagree") %>Strongly Disagree</li>
</ul>
</div>                              

<div class="row">
<ul>4b.  My customers have their own brand preferences regarding IP Surveillance manufacturers.<br/>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:surv, "Strongly Agree") %>Strongly Agree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:surv, "Somewhat Agree") %>Somewhat Agree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:surv, "Neutral") %>Neutral</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:surv, "Somewhat Disagree") %>Somewhat Disagree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:surv, "Strongly Disagree") %>Strongly Disagree</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My current validate in my Survey.rb model:

```
 class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :comments, :surv, :hardware, :voip, :quality, :revenue, :ucmrating, :noucm, :survey_taken, :user_id
 belongs_to :user

 validates :hardware, presence: true

 validates :revenue, presence: true
 validates :ucmrating, presence: true
 validates :noucm, presence: true
 validates :quality, presence: true

 validate :at_least_one_name

 def at_least_one_name
    if voip.blank? and surv.blank?

       return false
      elsif !voip.blank? and !surv.blank?

       return false
      else
       return true
     end   
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def create
params[:survey][:user_id] = current_user.id
params[:survey][:survey_taken] = true
@survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])
    if @survey.save
      flash[:success] = "Thank you for taking our survey."
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:error] = "Sorry, please fill out all of the survey questions."
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `:voip.blank?` whats this mean? this should be right! `voip.blank?`

Comment: I tried that. The form still gets submitted.

Comment: I'm not saying that this is the answer. I just pointed out that so do not. In the check symbol(`:voip.blank?`) of emptiness, and should call(`voip.blank?`)

Comment: Is return false correct? This is my first custom validator with RoR. Do I need something in the controller?

Comment: show you controller please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

you need to check any of the answers was chosen. This is done on the client side.You need a simple `javascript` that hides the button. Or check at the controller level.

**this is an just example.** 
on `controller` level check:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def create
    params[:survey][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params[:survey][:survey_taken] = true
    @survey = Survey.new(params[:survey])
    if validation  # <- return true if any params have
      if @survey.save
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for taking our survey."
        redirect_to current_user
      else
        flash[:error] = "Sorry, please fill out all of the survey questions."
        redirect_to current_user
      end
    end
  end

  private
  # Check if no one not selected
  def validation
    params[you_form][:voip].empty? && params[you_form][:surv].empty? ? false : true
  end
end
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to do first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509565/how-do-you-set-and-get-the-id-of-check-box-tag-for-javascript-function

Comment: check that would at least one selected

Comment: So this validates but it allows it to save before its validated :(

Comment: I used .nil? instead of .empty? Also placed the def validation as an instance variable. Used an if statement before the form saved. Thank you for the example. +1